# Suppose that $f\in C[a,b]$, $f(x)\leqslant \int_a^x f(t)dt$ over $[a,b]$, how to prove that $f(x)\leqslant 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I've tried as follows:

Write that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$, then $f(a)\leqslant F(a)=0$, let 
$$ S=\{x\in[a,b]\mid f(x)>0\},$$
and write $x_0=\inf{S}$, **I want to show that $x_0=b$**.

If $x_0<b$, then according to the continunity of $f$, $f(x_0)=0$, and $f(x)\leqslant 0, \forall x\in [a,x_0]$, thus $F(x_0)=\int_0^{x_0} f(t)dt\leqslant 0$, but we also have $F(x_0)\geqslant f(x_0)=0$. Then $f(x)\equiv 0$, ......

I cannot continue my proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, $S$ might be empty. It it better to define $x_0 = \sup R$, where $R = \{x \in [a,b]: f(x) \leq 0$ on $[a, x]\}$, and since you showed that $f(a) = 0$, $R$ is not empty and bounded by $b$.

You showed that $x_0 \not \in S$. So, it is the case that there are $x_n \in (x_0, b)$, $x_n \to x$ such that $F(x_n) > 0$.

Show that $f = 0$ identically for $x < x_0$. Now, $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt$.

Let $M$ be the maximum of $f$ on $[x_0, x_0 + \epsilon]$ for $\epsilon < \min(1, b-x_0)$? What does the inequality tell you about that maximum?

A hint for an easier solution: Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded by some $M > 0 $. Plug $f(x) \leq M$ into the inequality. What do you get? Plug it in again.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach using *differential inequalities*: Put $g(x):=F(x) e^{-x}$. Then $g'(x)=(F'(x)-F(x))e^{-x}\leq0$ by assumption. Thus $g$ is decreasing. Moreover $g(0)=0$ which implies $g(x)\leq g(0)=0$ for all $a\leq x\leq b$. This implies $F(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$. The assertion follows from $f(x)=F'(x)\leq F(x)\leq0$.

**Reference:** [Gronwall's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_0 <b$. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \in S$ and $x_n >x_0$ and $x_n \to x_0$. Since $f(x_n) >0$ for all $n$,  continuity gives  $f(x_0) \geq 0$. So $0\leq f(x_0) \leq \int_a^{x_0} f(t) \, dt \leq 0$ because $f(t) \leq0$ for all $t \in [a,x_0)$. We are assuming that $x_0 >a$. This gives $f\equiv 0$ in $[0,x_0]$. Now apply this argument with the interval $[a,b]$ replaced by $[z,c]$ where $z=\inf \{x\in [a,b]: f(u)$ is not identically $0$ for $a\leq u \leq x\}$. Since $f\equiv 0$ in $[a,z]$ the hypothesis holds for this new interval and we get a  contradiction to $x_0 <b$ in this case (by repeating the previous argument; note that (by definition of $z$) $f$ cannot vanish in a neighborhood of $z$). To handle the case when $x_0=a$ we do the following: let $g(x)=f(x)-\epsilon e^{x}$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied by $g$ in place of $f$. Further, $g(a)<0$. Hence, the point $x_0$ corresponding to this function is greater than $a$ and we get $g(x)=f(x)-\epsilon e^{x}\leq 0$. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ we get $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Why not $f(t) = 0$ for all $t < x_0$?

I don't think your proof follows.

Comment: About your update, what if $x_0 = a$ and $f > 0$ for all $x > a$. I don't see how what you did gets a contradiction.

Comment: @4-ier I have finally filled the hole in my proof. Please check the proof now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: First, strictly speaking, $S$ might be empty, so you would probably assume that $f > 0$ at some point so $S$ is non-empty. Second, besides the typos, up until "Hence, the point $x_0$" looks fine. I would note that $z = x_0$, because of the sequence $x_n \to x_0$ and $f = 0$ on $[a,x_0]$. Also, in order to get the existence of the sequence $x_n$, you need to show that the inf of $S$ is not a minimum of $S$, but that follows from continuity. So, could you explain yourself more in the last two sentences. Why is $g(x) \leq 0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: @4-ier The last part of my proof actually is applied in the beginning. It reduces the entire proof to the case when $f(a) <0$ (hence $f(x)<0$ near $a$).   If you work with a continuous function $f$ which satisfies the given inequality plus the condition $f(a)<0$ I don't think any of your objections is valid. (If $S$ is empty there is nothing to prove).

Comment: They weren't objections; they were comments.

Comment: @4 You have helped me to complete the argument based on the approach taken by the OP.  Thank you very much.

Comment: In the sentence that begins with "Since $f\equiv 0$ in $[a,z]$", I still don't get the contradiction.
Also, there are typos. For example, the next sentence is some case, but it doesn't say what $x_0$ equals.

Maybe you should reword your proof, making it clear that you have the claim $f(a) < 0$, then $f(x) \leq 0$. So, then since $g_\epsilon(a) < 0$, and $g_\epsilon \to f$, we have $f \leq 0$.